# Validate URL in text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to validate an URL in text input? I tried so many ways but it still won't work.

Comment: Can you try to console when there is no input? doe sit give you undefined or null ? you need to check for that also

Comment: the type="url" is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions. In which version did you try?

Comment: @SilentCoder i'm using chrome version 70

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input type="url">
```

Input type URL should be in quotes as defined [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/url)
 elements of type "url" are used to let the user enter and edit a URL.

Comment: i have tested on Version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit) with 
<button onclick="alert(document.getElementById('url').value)">Click me</button>
<input type="url"  placeholder="Upload an image" id="url"> and it's working fine.

Comment: yes, you are right. It is working only on Mozilla. Even the MDN website https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/url example is not showing red borders on wrong input in chrome

Answer (score 0):

You should add event listener for input for example:

```
const windowLocation = (inputId) => { 
    const changeHandler = (e) => {
        e.target.value !== '' ? window.location.assign(e.target.value) : alert("Please upload.")
    }
    const input = document.getElementById(inputId)
    input.addEventListener('change', changeHandler)
}
```

now you have to invoke function:

```
{
    windowLocation('url')
}
```

And if you typing on this input you should add some debouncer to prevent reload each time if you typing.

Cheers

Comment: debounce it is simple function with timeouts e.g https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function or https://codeburst.io/throttling-and-debouncing-in-javascript-b01cad5c8edf Cheers